# QPainter draw line between two widgets

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a layout, and I am going to add a button to this layout (by clicking on the add button).

Everytime I add a button, I wanna draw a line between Previous button and new button. This is done everytime I add a button. Also, The new button, has a clicked function that when I click it I delete this button and it's line draw between this button and previous one, and update the layout.

Seems complicated, but I see some application do this.Maybe they don't use same layout I am using.

@eyllanesc, helped to install this event, but it was more static. I need to make it more dynamic every time I update the layout. [Pyqt5 draw a line between two widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234724/pyqt5-draw-a-line-between-two-widgets). Below is some dummy trials of me

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class Drawer:
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawLine(self.p1, self.p2)


class Example(QWidget, Drawer):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.AddButton = QPushButton("Add")
        self.AddButton.clicked.connect(self.addbuttonwithline)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.AddButton)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Buttons")

    def addbuttonwithline(self):

        # Add buttons
        b = QPushButton('delete')
        self.vbox.addWidget(b)

        # delete the button and it's corresponding line
        b.clicked.connect(self.deletebuttonandlines)

        # Define buttons
        curr_ind = self.vbox.indexOf(b)
        previous_but = self.vbox.itemAt(curr_ind-1).widget()

        # Draw lines
        self.p1, self.p2 = previous_but.pos(), b.pos()

        previous_but.installEventFilter(self)
        b.installEventFilter(self)

    def deletebuttonandlines(self):
        # Delete this button and it's corresponding line and update the layout


    def eventFilter(self, o, e):
        if e.type() == QEvent.Move:
            self.p1 = self.p1
            self.p2 = self.p2
            self.update()
        return super().eventFilter(o, e)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is similar: Trace the events and changes (such as creating and destroying widgets) and then use the information to get the information to draw the lines:

```py
import functools
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, QLine
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class Drawer:
    def __init__(self):
        self._lines = []

    @property
    def lines(self):
        return self._lines

    @lines.setter
    def lines(self, l):
        self._lines = l[:]
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        for line in self.lines:
            painter.drawLine(line)


class Example(QWidget, Drawer):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.AddButton = QPushButton("Add")
        self.AddButton.clicked.connect(self.addbuttonwithline)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.AddButton)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Buttons")

        self.buttons = []

    def addbuttonwithline(self):
        button = QPushButton("delete")
        button.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.remove_button, button))
        button.installEventFilter(self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(button)
        self.buttons.append(button)
        self.recalculate_position()

    def remove_button(self, button):
        self.buttons.remove(button)
        button.deleteLater()
        self.recalculate_position()

    def recalculate_position(self):
        lines = []
        for last_button, next_button in zip(self.buttons, self.buttons[1:]):
            l = QLine(last_button.pos(), next_button.pos())
            lines.append(l)
        self.lines = lines

    def eventFilter(self, o, e):
        if e.type() == QEvent.Move and o in self.buttons:
            self.recalculate_position()
        return super().eventFilter(o, e)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Woow, Thanks a lot. You make things very easy. One more question. I am trying to set the line from the center of the QPushbutton, and start for the end of the previous to the beginning of the next. I tried this             '''l = QLine(last_button.pos().x()+50, last_button.pos().y()+10, next_button.pos().x()+50, next_button.pos().y()+10)''' But how can I replace the 50 to be at the center and y to be at the start.

Comment: Sorry @eyllanesc. I just face a problem when using QScrollArea with the QWidget. Lines are not appearing. Can you help me to fix that