# QPainter draw lines inside a QScrollArea

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qscrollarea

I raised a problem earlier on how to draw lines between widgets. and @eyllanesc solves it very well. But I faced another problem. I try to make the widget with QScrollarea. But the lines are not shown.

When using `Widget` it works fine with drawing lines, but seems QScrollArea need another `paint_event`. Don't know how to do that.

Can anyone help me to show lines with QScrollarea.

```
import functools
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, QLine
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QScrollArea


class Drawer:
    def __init__(self):
        self._lines = []

    @property
    def lines(self):
        return self._lines

    @lines.setter
    def lines(self, l):
        self._lines = l[:]
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        for line in self.lines:
            painter.drawLine(line)


class Example(QScrollArea, Drawer):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.AddButton = QPushButton("Add")
        self.AddButton.clicked.connect(self.addbuttonwithline)

        self.w = QWidget()
        self.setWidget(self.w)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self.w)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.AddButton)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Buttons")

        self.buttons = []

    def addbuttonwithline(self):
        button = QPushButton("delete")
        button.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.remove_button, button))
        button.installEventFilter(self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(button)
        self.buttons.append(button)
        self.recalculate_position()

    def remove_button(self, button):
        self.buttons.remove(button)
        button.deleteLater()
        self.recalculate_position()

    def recalculate_position(self):
        lines = []
        for last_button, next_button in zip(self.buttons, self.buttons[1:]):
            l = QLine(last_button.pos().x()+50, last_button.pos().y(), next_button.pos().x()+50, next_button.pos().y())
            lines.append(l)
        self.lines = lines

    def eventFilter(self, o, e):
        if e.type() == QEvent.Move and o in self.buttons:
            self.recalculate_position()
        return super().eventFilter(o, e)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QScrollArea is designed to be a container so you should not paint over that item since the content covers it, instead it sets the painting in the content widget.

Based on my code from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61783401/6622587) then just change to:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    w = QScrollArea(widgetResizable=True)
    w.setWidget(ex)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: I read some examples separating a QScrollarea, but your solution works very nicely . Thanks